# How to use a MIB file

Tags: switch, hp, hp-procurve, mib

I have a HP 2626 switch and want to monitor it by SNMP. how can i use the MIB file.
Any starting points on how to understand it ?
using `snmpwalk` to get the data in a *nix machine and output it in a .txt file

<strike>How can i get a list of all the connected mac-addresses and coresponding ports by snmp from a HP Procurve 2626 ? And then how can i get current port utilization by SNMP?</strike>

Comment: Check the MIB perhaps?

Comment: MIB but i don't know how to use it. any hints ?

Comment: What tool, on what platform, do you intend to use to do this?  At least gives us some clue of the platform you want to do it from.  Linux, perhaps?

Comment: Linux, i am using snmpwalk, but this returns me all the OID's from the device and i can not make sense of all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20090323043038/http://www.sifizm.com/2009/02/19/using-snmpget-or-snmpwalk-and-a-vendor-mib-file/

> First, copy your .mib file into the directory where your script is
> located.
>
> Then use snmpget in the following format:
>
> snmpget [address] -c [community string] -v 1 -m [mib name] [object to
> scan]
>
> Then use snmpwalk in the following format:
>
> snmpwalk [address] -c [community string] -v 1 -m [mib name] [object to
> scan]

On most Linux systems, the MIB files should go to `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` or probably `/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs`.

Comment: You can also `export MIBS=ALL` so snmpwalk will read every MIB in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` without having to list them all on the command line. Useful since HP probably gave you +/-8 billion MIB files.

Comment: yea' i have like 2 dozen files and will take ages to read them out :))

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Put STRANGE-NEW-MIB.txt in the directory where all your other MIBs are stored (possibly `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` , but it may vary with distro, mine is Fedora 14), then do

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public -m +STRANGE-NEW-MIB 1.2.3.4
```

where you replace `public` with the real RO community strong, `STRANGE-NEW-MIB` is the name of your new MIB without the .txt suffix (if memory serves), and `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of your switch.